# Recording web page events / ajax calls/results and so on

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, listener

I'm mostly looking for directions here.

I'm looking to record events that happen within a web page. Somewhat similar to your average "Macro-recorder", with the difference that I couldn't care less about exact cursor movement or keyboard input. The kind of events I would like record are modification of input fields, hovers, following links, submitting forms, scripts that are launched, ajax calls, ajax results and so on.

I've been thinking of using Jquery to build a little app for this, and inserting this on whichever pages I would like to test it on (or more likely, loading the pages into an iframe or something). I however can not accommodate the scripts on these pages to work with this so it has to work regardless of the content.

So I guess my first question is: Can this be done? Especially in regards to ajax calls and various script execution.
If it can, how would I go about the ajax/script part of it? If it can't, what language should I look into for this task?

Also: maybe there's something out there that can already do what I'm looking for?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Two ways I can think of are:

1. Use an add on (firefox) or an extension (chrome) to inject a script tags that loads jquery and your jquery app
2. Set a proxy (you can use node.js or some other proxy server) and in your proxy inject script tags, be sure to adjust the ContentLength header. (tricky in https sites).
3. A much simpler and faster option where you don't need to capture onload is to write a JavaScript snippet that load jquery and your app by inject script tags, make that a bookmarklet and after the page loads hit the bookmarklet.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the quick answer, these are all good ideas. I'll be sure to check them out. But my main concern here (before I even start) is whether or not I can actually record which scripts are being executed and in the case of ajax calls what the outgoing and incoming data is. All this with Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Came across this post when looking for a proxy for tag injection.

Yes it's quite possible to trap (nearly) all the function and method calls by a browser via code in a javascript loaded in the page - usually a javascript debugger (firebug?) or HTTP debugger (tamperdata / fiddler) will give you msot of what you require with a lot less effort.

OTOH if you really want to do this with bulk data / arbitary sites, then (based on what I've seen so far) you could use Squid proxy with an [icap server/ecap module](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/SquidFaq/ContentAdaptation) (not trivial - will involve a significant amount of programming) or implement the javascript via [greasemonkey](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greasemonkey) as a browser extension.

Just to clarify, so far I've worked out how to catch function and method (including constructor calls) and proxy then within my own code, but not yet how to deal with processing triggered by direct setting of a property (e.g. img.src='http://hackers-r-us.com') nor handle ActiveX neatly.